# What if the hosting Django server don't have the module I imported?

Tags: python, django

I have imported "smtplib" in the code, and I doubt that the server won't have this installed. Is there a CDN for modules in python ?

Comment: no, you have to install-it on the pythonpath

Comment: you can first install it on the server using pip command

Comment: `smtplib` is part of the python standard library. So dont worry. If a lib is not make uae of `pip` and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: If you don't control the python packages that are installed in your application's environment, you need a better hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You should save your dependencies in a requirements.txt file and use pip to install the requirements as part of your Django app's deployment process.

Edit: `smtplib` is part of the standard lib, so it should be available out of the box.

Comment: For third-party packages, yes. However smtplib is part of the standard library as does not need installing.